# Implement generic Regex.Matches with string tags

Tags: c#, string

I have a function that gets the content inside 2 tags of a string:

```
 string content = string.Empty;
 foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(stringSource, "<tag1>(.*?)</tag1>"))
 {
    content = match.Groups[1].Value;
 }
```

I need to do this operation many times with different tags. I want to update method so I can pass in the opening closing tags, but I can't concatenate the parameters of my tags with the regular expression. When I pass these values to the new function, the expression does not work:

```
public string GetContent(string stringSource, string openTag, string closeTag)
{
    string content = string.Empty;
    foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(stringSource, $"{openTag}(.*?){closeTag}"))
    {
        content = match.Groups[1].Value;
    }

    return content;
}
```

I want to use the function like this:

```
string content = GetContent(sourceString, "<tag1>", "</tag1>");
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: What do you mean by "the expression does not take me well"? Do you get an error? Unexpected results?

Comment: Exactly, unexpected results, I think it must be because of the way of concatenating the tags with the expression

Comment: Why not use an SGML parser, or something that is made for the markup language you are reading?

Comment: Obligatory https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3043

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetContent(string stringSource, string tag)
{
    foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(stringSource, $"<{tag}>(.*?)</{tag}>"))
    {
        yield return match.Groups[1].Value;
    }
}

// ...

var content = GetContent(sourceString, "tag1");
```

Note I also changed the return type. What you had before was the equivalent of calling this function like this: `string content = GetContent(sourceString, "tag").LastOrDefault();`

Also, [Regex is generally a poor choice for handling HTML and XML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3043). There are all kind of edge cases around this, such that RegEx really doesn't work that well.

You can make it *seem* to work if you can constrain your input to a subset of the language to limit edge cases, and that might get you by for a while, but usually someone will eventually want to use more of the features of the markup language and you'll start getting weird bugs and errors. *You'll really do much better with a dedicated, purpose-built parser!*

Comment: You can't assign `IEnumerable<string>` to `string`.

Comment: @PoulBak A little better now